# Where I should store code_verifier (oauth 2.0 code authorization flow with PKCE)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, pkce, oauth2orize

I'm currently working on an oauth 2.0 code authorization grant with PKCE in an SSR page (working with React in the front and Express in the back).

Where I should store `code_verifier` when client request to authorization server code (when authorization server creates code_challenge and code_verifier for verify latter). I have the authorization server running in an independent stack/infrastructure.

I should store `code_verifier` in req.headers ?
(see [Draft Campbell OAuth TBPKCE-00](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-campbell-oauth-tbpkce-00))

We are following [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

Comment: hey is it possible to share code samples which you already tried, it will help us to debug if you provide running code snippets and did you already google  your problem? it would be great if you let us know what you have already researched

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to think about storing it in `cookies`, it is an easy way and it is not a really big deal if someone sees it. You can use the `cookie-parser` library for **Node.js**, which I personally really like and use almost daily, as it provides **developer-friendly** tools.

**FYI:** I am working on mainly on **GraphQL** APIs, and I find a good solution also to store the `code_verifier` in the `context` of the GraphQL Server, e.g. **Apollo Server**.